# TYPO3: Compare two timestamps in Fluid-if

Tags: date, timestamp, conditional-statements, typo3, fluid

I'm not sure about how to write it correctly, but this is the inline notation I used, it seems to be correct from checking, but it always says it's greater.

`{f:if(condition: '{timestamp} > {f:format.date(date:{timestampsinloop}, format:"U")}', then: 'Too late')}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went back to half inline and half block notation:

`<f:if condition="{timestamp} > {f:format.date(date: '{timestampsinloop}', format: 'U')}">Too late</f:if>`

Comment: Maybe this has been removed in later Fluid versions. If I use it like that, I get an error - "A boolean expression has more than tree parts."